# Building Netbeans projects downloaded from github with broken references

Tags: netbeans

I downloaded https://github.com/shannah/CN1Sockets project

Why do I see in NetBeans 8.2 Libraries/Compile tab "Broken Reference: CN1Sockets-override"

I see this for most projects I have downloaded.

Can please you advise?

Answer (score 1):

FYI you can install cn1libs using project right click Codename One -> Codename One Settings -> Extensions then pick the cn1lib you want.

The reference is for the empty override directory. Empty directories aren't committed to git.